# ¿Por que no puedo borrar los datos de un vector?

Tags: java, array, poo, netbeans, bucle-for

Buenos dias tengo un problema y es que tengo un codigo de automoviles, en cual hay un vector que tiene varios datos, pero cada posicion de estos tiene las caracteristicas del coche y lo que quiero es cuando escoja la posicion del coche y la elimine ese coche, es un problema sencillo pero intente con "=null", pero me sirve si alguien me puede ayudar seria genial gracias

```
private void autoMovilesNuevos() throws IOException{  //POLIMORFISMOS
     
     PlantillaAuto vehiculos[] = new PlantillaAuto[7];
     
     vehiculos[0] = new PlantillaAuto(2000,4,600000,"RTX500","Rojo","Ferrari","QWE123");
     vehiculos[1] = new PlantillaAuto(2001,2,5000000,"GTX1200","Rojo","Chevorelt","QWT123");
     vehiculos[2] = new PlantillaAuto(2011,4,40000,"RTUX411","Verde","Ford","GHJ123");
     
     vehiculos[3] = new CocheDeportivo("No", "Si", 2020,2,61200000,"UVM123","Rojo","Ferrari","QWR123" );
     vehiculos[4] = new CocheDeportivo("SI", "Si", 2020,2,99900000,"HMQ1344","Negro","Porshe","QASB123" );
     
     vehiculos[5] = new CocheCamioneta(6,2019, 6 ,6912330,"ACV6566","Blanco","Mazda","QGS123" );
     vehiculos[6] = new CocheCamioneta(8,2019, 8 ,1231330,"ACV6566","Marron","Chevrolet","ASD125" );

     for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Opcion " + (i+1) + " " + vehiculos[i]);
     }
     System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion del coche");
     int option = (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))-1;
     System.out.println(vehiculos[option]);
     System.out.println("¿Esta seguro?,(si,no)");
     String sure = br.readLine();
     if (sure.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
         
         boolean flag = false;  //bandera para controlar la ejecucion del bucle

         for (int i = 0; !flag && i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {   
             if (listaCliente.get(i).getPresupuesto()>=vehiculos[option].getPrecio()) {
                 flag=true;
                 System.out.println("Felicidades Disfruta tu ¡Nuevo Coche! ");
                 vehiculos[option]=null;  //fix como borro este dato ??
```

Comment: Primero que nada, has pasado un código que nunca jamás compilaría porque has puesto solo un trocito. Te recomiendo que cuando busques ayuda utilices un [mre], y sobre todo, que lo que pases funcione, porque me podría pasar una hora intentando ver qué es lo que falla en ese código! Por supuesto, ***ayudaría muchísimo que nos digas por qué NO puedes borrar***, pues "no sirve" no ayuda nada

Comment: "no sirve", me refiero a que no lo borra sigue ahi, y si coloco el main tendria que colocar todo mi codigo de 1000 lineas, ya que esta es una opcion del programa, ademas el problema que coloque del codigo esta lo mas simplificado no entiendo porque ejemplo mínimo verificable,

Comment: No puedo ver el flujo de tu programa pero imagino que cada vez que eliges esa opción entras al método `autoMovilesNuevos()` de nuevo, no?? SI es así, dado que cada vez que entras estás volviendo a crear todos los automóviles... por mucho que lo borres, luego lo vuelves a añadir

Comment: si cada vez que eligo esa opción entro al método autoMovilesNuevos(), que me recomiendas hacer en ese caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cada vez que entras al método recreas todos los vehículos, nunca permanecerán borrados. Podrías intentar algo así:

```
public class NombreDeTuClase{
    // Ahora tenemos el array como miembro de la clase en vez de dentro del método
    private PlantillaAuto vehiculos[];

    public NombreDeTuClase(){
        //Instanciamos y añadimos los vehículos en el constructor
        vehiculos[] = new PlantillaAuto[7];
        vehiculos[0] = new PlantillaAuto(2000,4,600000,"RTX500","Rojo","Ferrari","QWE123");
        vehiculos[1] = new PlantillaAuto(2001,2,5000000,"GTX1200","Rojo","Chevorelt","QWT123");
        vehiculos[2] = new PlantillaAuto(2011,4,40000,"RTUX411","Verde","Ford","GHJ123");
        vehiculos[3] = new CocheDeportivo("No", "Si", 2020,2,61200000,"UVM123","Rojo","Ferrari","QWR123" );
        vehiculos[4] = new CocheDeportivo("SI", "Si", 2020,2,99900000,"HMQ1344","Negro","Porshe","QASB123" );
        vehiculos[5] = new CocheCamioneta(6,2019, 6 ,6912330,"ACV6566","Blanco","Mazda","QGS123" );
        vehiculos[6] = new CocheCamioneta(8,2019, 8 ,1231330,"ACV6566","Marron","Chevrolet","ASD125" );
        // Otras cosas que hagas en el constructor....
    }
    
    
    private void autoMovilesNuevos() throws IOException{  //POLIMORFISMOS
    //Ahora el array ya no se llena aquí! Se llena en el constructor
     for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Opcion " + (i+1) + " " + vehiculos[i]);
     }
     System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion del coche");
     int option = (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))-1;
     System.out.println(vehiculos[option]);
     System.out.println("¿Esta seguro?,(si,no)");
     String sure = br.readLine();
     if (sure.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
         
         boolean flag = false;  //bandera para controlar la ejecucion del bucle

         for (int i = 0; !flag && i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {
             if (listaCliente.get(i).getPresupuesto()>=vehiculos[option].getPrecio()) {
                 flag=true;
                 System.out.println("Felicidades Disfruta tu ¡Nuevo Coche! ");
                /* Ahora cuando pongas esto a null, estarás usando el array de la 
                clase, que nunca se volverá a recrear hasta que no instancies otro
                objeto de esta clase. Esto te permite tener "permanencia" entre las
                diferentes llamadas a este método (o cualquier otro)
                */
                 vehiculos[option]=null;
             }
         }
     }

    // Otros métodos de tu clase....

}
```

En los comentarios encontrarás todos los cambios que hice así como la explicación.

Los nombres de las clases me los he inventado, puesto que no los has especificado. De todas maneras, debería serte fácil adaptarlo para que funcione correctamente con tu código.

---

Una última cosa, ten cuidado con los NullPointerException, porque veo que *borras* las cosas poniéndolas a null, pero a la hora de trabajar con los vehículos nunca veo que hagas null checks, eso te va a dar NPE en todas partes así!